# How Create Global Array and save Values in Two TableViews in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, global-variables

Here i am creating Global array and appending values to it, which i need to save in two different viewcontrollers tableview

**Global array and appending values and sending to two view controllers code:**

```
var addressArray = [String]()
class NewZoomAddressViewController: UIViewController {

weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = nil

//var addressArray = [String]()
var zipName: String?
var localityName: String?
var sublocalityName: String?
var streetNumber: String?
var streetName: String?

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!

var viewController: UIViewController?

@IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {
             for controller in navigationController?.viewControllers ?? [] {
                  if let listController =  controller as? ProfileViewController {

                      let string = "\(streetNumber ?? "") \(streetName ?? "") \(sublocalityName ?? "") \(zipName ?? "") \(localityName ?? "")"
                    saveaddAddressService()
                      listController.addressArray.append(string)
                    navigationController?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
                      return
                  }

               else if let listController =  controller as? Add_EditAddressViewController {

                    let string = "\(sublocalityName ?? "") \(zipName ?? "") \(localityName ?? "")"
                    listController.addressArray.append(string)
                    saveaddAddressService()
                    navigationController?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
                    return
                }
              }
  }

 func saveaddAddressService(){

    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
                        "pincode": zipName,
                        "city": localityName,
                        "streetName": sublocalityName,
                        "colony": "",

                    ]
                    //some JSON code.....
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                if httpResponse!.statusCode == 200 {
                    do {
                        let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String: Any]
                        self.addAddrsID = jsonObject["addressId"] as! String
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.addAddrsID, forKey: "addAddress")

                    } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

**Saving array in first view controller view controllers**: here i am getting each time with new address the model address also coming, i dont know why?

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

var userModel : ProfileModel?
var addressArray = [String]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden=true
 getUserProfile()
 }
func getUserProfile() {
let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
if httpResponse!.statusCode == 200 {
    do {
        let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String :AnyObject]
        self.userModel = ProfileModel.init(fromDictionary: jsonObject)

        if (self.userModel?.userId) != nil {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateUserDetails()
                self.addressTableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

if userModel?.userAddresses != nil{
    return userModel?.userAddresses.count ?? 0
}
else{
    return addressArray.count
}
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: AddresCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddresCell") as! AddresCell
let addr = userModel?.userAddresses![indexPath.row]
if addr?.addressId != nil{

              let street = addr?.streetName
              let colony = addr?.colony
              let city   = addr?.city
               let pincode = addr?.pincode
                cell.address.text = street! + "," + colony! + "," + city! + "," + pincode!
}
else{
        cell.address.text = addressArray[indexPath.row]
        print("added address in profilr \(cell.address.text)")
}
    return cell
}
```

**saving global array in second view controller**: here array values are coming, but if i go from this view controller to other view controller the array values gone(not coming.. showing empty.. not saving)

```
class Add_EditAddressViewController: UIViewController,DataEnteredDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var addeditTableview: UITableView!
var addressArray = [String]()
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    addeditTableview.reloadData()
}
}
extension Add_EditAddressViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return addressArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditAddressTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! EditAddressTableViewCell

    cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editbuttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.nameHeader.text = "Other"
        cell.addressLabel.text = addressArray[indexPath.row]//"\(city) \(pincode) \(locality)"

    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Don't do that. Don't create variables outside of classes/structs/enums. Declare the array in the main view controller and hand it over in the segue or instantiation. And it's quite confusing  to use the name `addressArray` for multiple **different** objects in the same scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a singleton class to manage your global array like below GlobalArrayManager class:

```
import Foundation
class GlobalArrayManager{
    static let shared = GlobalArrayManager()
    var globalArray : [Int] = []
    private init(){}

    func getArray()->[Int]{
        return globalArray
    }

    func addDataInArray(data : Int){
        globalArray.append(data)
    }
}
```

In first ViewController add data and print:

```
GlobalArrayManager.shared.addDataInArray(data: 100)
print("array values : ",GlobalArrayManager.shared.getArray())
```

Output In first ViewController:

```
array values :  [100]
```

In second ViewController add data and print:

```
GlobalArrayManager.shared.addDataInArray(data: 200)
print("array values : ",GlobalArrayManager.shared.getArray())
```

Output  In Second ViewController:

```
array values :  [100, 200]
```

you can add more functionalities in your manager class

Comment: actually you slightly misunderstood the question.. actually i am appending values to array in `NewZoomAddressViewController ` ... here this appended array need to show in two above mentioned view controller without deleting data while moving to other view controller

Comment: In my given example I have adde value 100 from first viewController then in Second view controller I have added 200. When I  printed array from second viewController both 100 and 200 appears

Comment: no i am adding all values to arry in `NewZoomAddressViewController ` which i need to show in two other view controllers...... no need to add values to array in two view controllers

Comment: the process I have explained , you can use that to add data from anywhere and read that data from anywhere. No data will be lost.

Comment: okay i have added data to array `GlobalArrayManager.shared.addDataInArray(data: 100)` then how to show that data in tabelview cell and how to return `numberOfRowsInSection `

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection   = GlobalArrayManager.shared.getArray().count

Comment: to show data in table view you can get vaule GlobalArrayManager.shared.getArray()[indexPath.row] . here if indexPath.row = 0 then you will get 100

Comment: @iOSApp did you try?

Comment: yes but when i stop the app and run again then data missing in tabelview, do u know why data missing.. when stop and run

Comment: You have to save data in userdefaults or database (coredata, salute etc) to get them after restarting the app otherwise these data will be lost when you kill your app.